# Addition to number formed using number_format() php function

Tags: php

When i try to add a integer to 3 digit number formed using php number_format() function give right result but when number become 4 digit it give wrong output.

I have tried this. please explain me the reason behind this??

```
$num1=number_format(1000.5,2);
$num1+=1;
echo $num1;
```

**Output:2**

But

```
  $num1=number_format(100.5,2);
  $num1+=1;
  echo $num1."\n";`
```

**Output:101.5**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`number_format()` returns a string not a number. It is there to format a numeric type (integer, float) to a string with a specific, desired "layout". So what you do is add the number `1` to the string resulting from `number_format`, which will try to cast the string back to a number, apparently resulting in `1` for the string cast as well, which gives you 2 total.

tl;dr; Do calculations on numbers only and then do `number_format` at the very end to output in a defined format.

Comment: but why  $num1=number_format(100.5,2);
  $num1+=1;
  echo $num1."\n"; give putput 101.5

Comment: Because 1000.5 results in the string `1,000.50`, so the string to integer parser stops at the first non numeric char (in this case the `,`) resulting in 1.
For 100.5 the formatted string is `100.50` so stopping again at the first non numeric char gives 100.

Answer (score 1):

```
$num1 = number_format(1000.5, 2);
var_dump($num1);
// => string(8) "1,000.50"

$num1 += 1;
var_dump($num1);
// => int(2)
```

Function [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) returns string.

And that string is type cast to integer when you are adding 1

See [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: but why $num1=number_format(100.5,2); $num1+=1; echo $num1."\n"; give putput 101.5

Comment: $num1 = number_format(100.5, 2);
    var_dump($num1);
    // => string(6) "100.50"

This string doesn't contain a coma delimiter ',' in it.

That is why it is converted to a float, and that is why you get different result.

Comment: // => string(8) "1,000.50"

First number has a ',' - thousands separator in it.

And the second number doesn't have it, as it is <1000.

Comment: Please, have a look at [String conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution would be using [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on your formatted number.
Something like this would do:

```
(float)str_replace( ',', '', $formatted_number )
```

By removing the commas from the string and asking for the float value, you'll get a usable number.